# WS02 AM - Getting ClientId and Client Secret programatically

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I have been looking through the docs etc and found the curl request

```
curl -X POST -H "Authorization: Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4=" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d @payload.json http://localhost:9763/client-registration/v0.9/register
```

with a given json payload of

```
{
"callbackUrl": "www.google.lk",
"clientName": "rest_api_store",
"tokenScope": "Production",
"owner": "admin",
"grantType": "password refresh_token",
"saasApp": true
```

}

My question is, where do I find the clientName for my existing APIs/Apps

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could use OAuthAdminService admin service to get application related data

```
https://localhost:9443/services/OAuthAdminService?wsdl
```

You can view the wsdl file by setting following to false in carbon.xml file

```
<HideAdminServiceWSDLs>false</HideAdminServiceWSDLs>
```